# ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING on angularjs - rest service returns an infinite json file using Advanced REST Client but error in postman

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, json, rest

I have a very strange problem. In angular (app built with ionic v1) I call some REST call built in java, but something goes wrong and chrome advise me with this error:
[image: ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING]

The code interesting is this, a REST service in angular js:

```js
bankaccountsbyuser: function(_getbauser, _error){
            var currentToken = _GetToken();
  
            if(currentToken!=null){
                var Headers = {
                    token: currentToken.tokenUser,
                };
            }
            
            _timerTokenControl(currentToken, _error);
            
            if (setupTime == null) {
                console.log("token scaduto");
                //modificare
                //$window.location.href="login.html";
            }
            

            if (currentToken !== null) {
            $http({  
                        method : 'GET',  
                        headers: Headers,
                        url : REST_URL+'bankaccount'
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {  
                        console.log(response)
                        _getbauser(response)
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {  
                        console.log(response.statusText);  
                    });  
               }  else {
                   var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                         title: 'Accesso negato!',
                         template: 'Devi essere un utente registrato, non sei loggato!'
                     });
                    console.log("NON SEI LOGGATO!!!");
            }
        },
```

debug:
[image: debug]

How you can see, the get REST service returns an error, thus, let's see this REST service built in java:

```html
package it.jack.fdd.services;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import it.jack.fdd.dao.FactoryDao;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.impl.BankAccountDaoImpl;
import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.BankAccountDao;
import it.jack.fdd.domain.BankAccount;
import it.jack.fdd.domain.User;
import it.jack.fdd.dto.TokenUserDto;
import it.jack.fdd.dto.UserDto;
import it.jack.fdd.util.ConverterDTO;

@Path("/bankaccount")
public class BankAccountServices {

 @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public List<BankAccount> getBankAccountOfUser() {
   
  BankAccountDao baDao = new BankAccountDaoImpl();
  List<BankAccount> balist = baDao.getBAByUserId(1);  
  return balist;

 }
```

I tryed to pass the number "1" in the method, just to simplify. The method is implemented below:

```html
package it.jack.fdd.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import it.jack.fdd.dao.interfaces.BankAccountDao;
import it.jack.fdd.domain.BankAccount;
import it.jack.fdd.domain.Staff;
import it.jack.fdd.domain.User;
import it.jack.fdd.util.HibernateUtilLezione;

public class BankAccountDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl<BankAccount> implements BankAccountDao{
 

 public List<BankAccount> getBAByUserId(int id) {
  
  try{
   
   Session session = HibernateUtilLezione.openSession();
   Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
   
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   List<BankAccount> accounts = session.createQuery("from BankAccount b "
     + "where b.user= "+id).list();
   
   tx.commit();
   session.close();
   
   return accounts;
  }
  catch(HibernateException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
   return null;
  }
 }
 
}
```

As you can see, the method ask for an id, and I put id 1 just to check, because in the database there is a field with that id. Trying in java, it returns me a list

> [it.jack.fdd.domain.BankAccount@4f8d86e4]

And I checked also that the list has dimension 1 (thus, only one record, like in the database, only 1 record with that iduser)

Thus, trying to open this REST call using postman, the result is this:

[image: Postman error]

The strange thing is that postman show me the same result to another REST call, that it worked before. But for this last REST call is not a problem, because strangely it works on my application, it doesn't work only in postman.
Thus, trying with Advanced REST Client I have a strange different result:

[image: Advanced rest client 1]

A strange, very big list that repeat every time the same field!! It is like a loop! 
What happens? How I can solve?

Comment: @Hema I solved! Look the solution

Comment: Predicted this.. So only asked u to share your Entity class... Good that u solved it

Comment: OK, I will post my entity class

Comment: Posted in the solution. I hope that this will help u

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: That you need help! I posted the solution before your answer.. But don't worry, thank you anyway

Comment: Ha ha why to worry.Chill Happy coding..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was in java's domain classes: when a domain class has a one-to-many relationship it's mandatory to put the tag @JsonIgnore to avoid these recurrent records in json file[image: Example]

Entity class:

```js
package it.jack.fdd.domain;
// Generated 30-nov-2016 0.17.09 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1.Final

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 * BankAccount generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "bank_account", catalog = "fdd_dbproducts")
public class BankAccount implements java.io.Serializable {

 private Integer idbankAccount;
 private User user;
 private String iban;
 private String pin;
 private String society;
 private Date expiration;

 public BankAccount() {
 }

 public BankAccount(User user, String iban, String pin, String society) {
  this.user = user;
  this.iban = iban;
  this.pin = pin;
  this.society = society;
 }

 public BankAccount(User user, String iban, String pin, String society, Date expiration) {
  this.user = user;
  this.iban = iban;
  this.pin = pin;
  this.society = society;
  this.expiration = expiration;
 }

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

 @Column(name = "idbank_account", unique = true, nullable = false)
 public Integer getIdbankAccount() {
  return this.idbankAccount;
 }

 public void setIdbankAccount(Integer idbankAccount) {
  this.idbankAccount = idbankAccount;
 }

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "fkuser_baccount", nullable = false)
 public User getUser() {
  return this.user;
 }

 public void setUser(User user) {
  this.user = user;
 }

 @Column(name = "iban", nullable = false, length = 45)
 public String getIban() {
  return this.iban;
 }

 public void setIban(String iban) {
  this.iban = iban;
 }

 @Column(name = "pin", nullable = false, length = 45)
 public String getPin() {
  return this.pin;
 }

 public void setPin(String pin) {
  this.pin = pin;
 }

 @Column(name = "society", nullable = false, length = 45)
 public String getSociety() {
  return this.society;
 }

 public void setSociety(String society) {
  this.society = society;
 }

 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 @Column(name = "expiration", length = 10)
 public Date getExpiration() {
  return this.expiration;
 }

 public void setExpiration(Date expiration) {
  this.expiration = expiration;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only for the onetomany but for manytomany relationships put the @JsonIgnore tag in the modelclass